# Error in PL/SQL Bubble sorting program

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a PL/SQL bubble sorting program but it is giving a:

```
Error "ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit"
```

error. Kindly help me to resolve it as I am new to PL/SQL, the code is:

```
DECLARE
      temp int;
      type first is VARRAY(6) of integer;
      arr first;
      i integer;
      j integer;
BEGIN
      i:=0;
      j:=1;
      temp:=0;
      arr:=first(3,1,4,2,5,9);
      FOR i in 0..4 LOOP
          FOR j in 1..5 LOOP
             if arr(i)>arr(j) then
                temp:=arr(i);
                arr(i):=arr(j);
                arr(j):=temp;
             end if;
          END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
     FOR i in 0..5 LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(arr(i));
     END LOOP;

END
```

Comment: I've got to ask. Why do you feel the need to write a sort program in a language that exists only inside a DBMS, something exquisitely tuned to sort with an `order by` clause?

Comment: i am trying to learn this language concepts...and practicing the algorithm gives you good hands on language...

Comment: No probs, it seemed an unusual choice but, if it's for education, I applaud it.

Comment: yes i am trying to learn pl/sql language , at one time i had not interest in that language but gradually i found that it is very useful to learn a database language as we learn desktop,web,mob languages.

Comment: i have changed indexes but now output is not right now....but thanks to u that u solved my indexes problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL arrays are one-based rather than zero-based.

Hence the indexes you need to use are 1..6 rather than 0..5.

That should solve your immediate problem. Whether your algorithm will work may be another matter, it looks like a hybrid between bubble and selection sorts - the former tends to only compare adjacent elements.

But fixing the array index out of bounds issue is your first step.

Comment: Now i have changed my code as you suggested but output is not right now...below is changed code..

    DECLARE

    temp int;
    type first is VARRAY(6) of integer;
    arr first;
    i integer;
    j integer;
    BEGIN
       i:=1;
       j:=2;
       temp:=0;
       arr:=first(3,1,4,2,5,9);
       FOR i in 1..5 LOOP
          FOR j in 2..6 LOOP
           if arr(i)>arr(j) then
            temp:=arr(i);
              arr(i):=arr(j);
              arr(j):=temp;
            end if;
    END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
    FOR i in 1..6 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(arr(i));
    END LOOP;

    END;

Comment: yes that is the bubble sort algorithm in which adjacent elements are compared if first is larger then second they are swapped this swapping continues until whole array is sorted.